# WMTS not numbered from 0/0 with OL3js

Tags: openlayers-2, wmts

I am requesting a WMTS which does not number tiles from 0/0, but from some arbitrary given number. Is it possible to deal with this with openlayers 3?
I thought WMTS should have defined first tile of every tile matrix as 0/0, should not it?